# Product status defaulting to disabled

Tags: commerce

I am having a weird issue from one of our client web sites. When a user goes to add a product through the /admin/commerce/products/add/product, the status form field isn't rendered (by design). The database sets the default value to 1 (active) however when the user adds the product it sets the status to "Disabled".

I have looked all around and I can't figure out how this is being changed. Any ideas where I should be looking to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

There's no telling without seeing the code you've used to hide the status field. My bet is the way you've hidden it is causing the form system to interpret the absence of a value as the disabled status, given PHP would treat both a 0 value and a NULL value similarly.